# drag element to left and right with autoscroll

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, draggable

I have a button that adds columns (wrappers) and in that columns I have button to add rows. When there are lots of rows a scrollbar appears (I have overflow-y:auto on the wrapper). Those rows are draggable and when I drag them and bring closer to bottom or top it autoscrolls in that direction. Here is the code.

```
dragOver(event: DragEvent, wrapper: HTMLDivElement): void {
        const bottomTask = this.insertAboveTask(wrapper, event.clientY)
        const curTask = document.querySelector('.dragging')
        const lastChild = wrapper.lastElementChild;

        if(!bottomTask) {
            wrapper.insertBefore(curTask!, lastChild)
        } else {
            wrapper.insertBefore(curTask!, bottomTask)
        }

        const scrollThreshold = 50;
        const containerRect = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
        const isNearTop = (event.clientY - containerRect.top) < scrollThreshold;
        const isNearBottom = (containerRect.bottom - event.clientY) < scrollThreshold;

        if (isNearTop) {
            // Calculate the scroll speed based on the distance from the top
            const scrollSpeed = (scrollThreshold - (event.clientY - containerRect.top)) / scrollThreshold;
            const scrollAmount = scrollSpeed * 3

            // Scroll the container upwards with a smooth behavior
            wrapper.scrollTo({
                top: wrapper.scrollTop - scrollAmount,
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        } else if (isNearBottom) {
            // Calculate the scroll speed based on the distance from the bottom
            const scrollSpeed = (scrollThreshold - (containerRect.bottom - event.clientY)) / scrollThreshold;
            const scrollAmount = scrollSpeed * 3

            // Scroll the container downwards with a smooth behavior
            wrapper.scrollTo({
                top: wrapper.scrollTop + scrollAmount,
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        }
    }

    insertAboveTask(wrapper: HTMLDivElement, mouseY : number) {
        const els = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.row:not(.dragging)')

        let closestTask: null | Element = null
        let closestOffset = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY

        els.forEach(task => {
            const {top} = task.getBoundingClientRect()

            const offset = mouseY - top - 40 

            if (offset < 0 && offset > closestOffset) {
                closestOffset = offset
                closestTask = task
            }
        })

        return closestTask

    }
```

I want to do the same with the body. Body has css property overflow-x:auto and when there are a lot of columns (wrappers) a scrollbar appears. So i want to drag an element and bring it and put in the last column. How to autoscroll to left or right through the body element when i bring the dragged row near?

Thanks for the help!